# Are SSO capabilities already built in for the listed Service Providers in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I have configured multiple service providers which provider OAuth2.0 Authorization which use WSO2 as the identity provider. When I login to one of these service providers, I am successfully logged into the application. When I visit the other service provider, I am logged in as well. I have a few questions about this.

1. Is this considered SSO, as I am granted sign on between all my Service Providers after logging into one?
2. How does WSO2 IS know I was logged in to another Service Provider? Does it work by session cookies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering Q1 Yes. That can be considered as SSO but may need to combine openid connect with oauth2 authorization to get end user attributes to service provider

Answering to Q2 commonAuthId cookie will be used to handle authenticated session between multiple tabs in same browser