# WSO2 IS : How to login to multiple service providers simultaneously?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am pretty new to the WSO2 IS and my object is to understand how ( *whether its possible* ) to enable simultaneous login of 2 different service provider applications. 
For instance : token from one service provider is to be accessed and used to login to the other app.
Any help on this topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> how ( whether its possible ) to enable simultaneous login of 2 different service provider applications.

From this question, I understand that you want to try Single Sign on with Identity server. WSO2 Identity Server enables users to access multiple applications using the same set of credentials. For an example, if users log into application A, they would automatically have access to application B as well for the duration of that session without having to re-enter their credentials. WSO2IS provides the capability for SSO using different protocols such as OpenIDConnect, SAML, etc.

If this is your requirement, you can refer to this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) to know about Single sign-on. If you use OAuth apps you can get access tokens. Refer to this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On) to know about SSO with OpenID Connect.

Comment: I have the scenario that there would be 2 instances running of the same application and if I log in into one of its instance the other one should also be logged in of same credentials. Is it possible to use the same tokens for 2 instances of same application ? running in 2 different browser instance ?

Comment: If you are having different browser sessions, SSO is not possible. SSO happens based on commonAuthId cookie. You can refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114284/are-sso-capabilities-already-built-in-for-the-listed-service-providers-in-wso2-i